# Detect if Windows "daylight saving time adjustement" is enabled in Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, dst

I would like to detect if OS daylight saving time adjustement is enable or not.
Do you think it's possible in Javascript ?

[image: daylight saving time adjustement]

This is in order, to display a datetime aligned with all OS time configurations.

**Example:**

When I run the snippet at bottom with OS daylight saving time adjustment "Off": I get the result below. But I would like to display a date without daylight saving time adjustment **if** it's disabled in my OS.

[image: Example with daylight saving time adjustement disabled]

```js
document.write(Date());
```

Comment: Do you want to check this from the browser? If so, the answer is "no, you cannot check it".

Comment: Yes, I would like to do it from the browser. Do you have any documentation or explanations on this limitation?

Comment: The browser limits almost all interactions with the OS. I'm not sure how I can show you documentation for the specific things that aren't allowed when it's basically everything. Code running on the browser has almost no information from the OS outside what the browser supplies, like dates, for example. Even then, those can be spoofed - `new Date()` might not even be reading the OS time.